# What do i need to connect to clock_enable pin from VHDL box in Signadyne FPGA?

Tags: fpga, vhdl, clock, hdl

I have this digital filter box (it's VHDL vodule that i get from matlab hdlgenerator) [image: Filter_box_VHDL]
I want to know, what do i should connect to clock_enable pin?
If it possible i really want a comprehensive response)
P.S. sorry for bad pic

Comment: First you have to decide under what circumstances you want the filter to be enabled. Then you have to create a circuit that meets that requirement. Connect its output to the clock enable pin.

Comment: always, i have waveform generator on this plate, and i want 1 channel output was filtered by them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know this particular module, but usually this pin just enables block. So if you want this block to work all the time, just connect it to constant '1'. If you want to enable it only for some time, connect it to some logic, that will enable it, or for example to soft processor (like Microblaze), or to PL if this is Zynq.

Comment: great thanks, i do this

[link to imgurPic](http://imgur.com/5vTyLVw)